# PHP Socket: Timeout and disable warnings

Tags: php, sockets, timeout, warnings

I've got a simple question regarding socket_connect() for PHP.
I'm using ajax to send a request on the fly to a script that connects to my server.
When I get the result back I either get the value I want if the server was up, or I get "?" if the server was down.

This is all great but two things:

- If socket_connect() fails (if the server is down) it will output a really huge warning on my page from the result. How do I disable this warning or any warnings that socket_connect or socket_send will output? I don't want to be cheap and just disable all PHP warnings as this isn't efficient.
- When it fails to connect, the timeout is pretty huge. I've tried socket_set_option but it still takes around 15 seconds:

  ```
  socket_set_option($sock,  SOL_SOCKET,  SO_SNDTIMEO,  array("sec"=>2, "usec"=>0) );
  ```

Also Merry Christmas!

Comment: You could use `try` and `catch`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I suppose I could, I didn't think that would get rid of the warnings.

Also I've read about the only way to stop timeout would be to use a non-blocking socket. Is it possible with a blocking socket?

Comment: I don't know about the socket timeout, but try and catch should you give control about the warning.

Comment: try to put `@` before: `@socket_connect()`, it should suppress warnings.. i hope

Comment: Okay I got the warnings to go away but now is the problem with the timeout...

Using a nonblocking socket works however its periodically connecting to my server....